# Is the following sentence grammaticaly correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I read a book about how to become rich, and I came across this sentence.

> I want tough men that gargle the blood of their victims not like women get melted when the door slams.

Is that sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: No, that sentence is not entirely grammatical. Then again, "books about how to become rich" are often only making the author rich, and it doesn't matter if the language is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this sentence is not correct English. Perhaps it is a bad translation from another language.

The first clause is okay but the second clause is gramatically incorrect.  It could be improved to read :

> I want tough men who gargle the blood of their victims, not women who melt when the door slams.

"Get melted" is probably intended to mean that the women "faint" or "quake" or "get scared" when the door slams. So "get scared" would be ok but not "get melted".

Comment: In English the phrase would be "go into meltdown". However, this usually means that someone becomes enraged, like a child having a tantrum. I think the author is trying to convey that the women are so weak with fear that they cannot do anything. They are no longer solid and strong like ice, they lose their strength and are easily pushed around like water.